# System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, windows-services, access-violation

I have a windows service created with .net framework 3.5 in visual studio 2008.
When i run my service on the 32 bit windows XP machine, the service runs properly.

However, when i install the same service on the windows 7 64 bit machine i get the following error:
"System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"

I have checked out other threads on the same subject, but none of the answers provided have helped me.

Kindly help me on this.

Thanx a lot in advance

R/
Sachin